# How to use image_picker plugin in flutter desktop without go-flutter

Tags: image, flutter, picker, flutter-desktop

Am trying to user image_picker plugin in my flutter desktop project, but i think there is no implementation for this plugin that work with windows desktop app. 
Did someone have a solution for that ? 
Ps : i want use go-flutter and hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

- [Implement the plugin for Windows](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/plugins/README.md#writing-your-own-plugins).
- Use [FDE's file_chooser plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/file_chooser) (once [the Windows implementation lands](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/pull/651)) and set a file type filter for the image types you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
File image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  Future getImage(ImageSource src) async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: src);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print("no image selected");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).