# How to pick Image from local storage in Flutter Windows app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am creating an Application consist of  **Form()** where I need to insert a picture available in local storage (i.e: Document Directory).

Android, IOS, and Web using **ImagePicker** Package. but what should I use for windowsOS?

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe this question can help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897337/how-to-use-image-picker-plugin-in-flutter-desktop-without-go-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897337/how-to-use-image-picker-plugin-in-flutter-desktop-without-go-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Flutter plugin to select, open, choose, pick and create documents, images videos or other files on Android, iOS, the desktop and the web for reading, writing, use as String, byte list or HTTP uploads.

```
file_picker_cross: ^4.4.2
```